# ¿Como setear una variable sin sesiones php?

Tags: php, laravel, sesiones

Estoy haciendo un login con redes sociales utilizando laravel Socialite, sin embargo necesito guardar una variable que es el origen de la pagina donde se esta registrando.

Según la documentación yo tengo en mi controlador los siguientes métodos.

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider, $origen)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['origen'] = $origen;
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}
```

Esta función se ejecuta cuando entrar a la url de login que tiene la siguiente forma

```
https://mi-dominio.com/auth/red-social/origen
```

Como ven en el método redirectToProvider hago una sesión en la cual guardo el origen.

Quisiera que este set se hiciera de esta forma.

```
protected $provider, $origen;

public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $argumentes = $request->route()->parameters();
    $this->provider = $argumentes['provider'];
    $this->origen = $argumentes['origen'];
}
```

Para no utilizar sesiones, pero el problema es que se pierde la instancia cuando salgo del dominio hacia el dominio de la red social. Y cuando retorna, los valores de $provider y $origen están en null por lo que ya no los puedo reutilizar.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como puedo hacer esto sin que se pierda la instancia.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el propósito de esa variable? ¿es para indicar qué red social utilizar?

Comment: No tengo diferentes urls:
mi-dominio.com/{origen-del-dominio}
El guardar esto nos ayuda analizar que estrategias de marketing no están funcionando mejor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar directamente las variables de session de laravel sin necesidad de usar 
`session_start()`:

setear valor:

```php
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

recuperar valor:

```
$value = $request->session()->get('key');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias el segundo método es mas elegante que utilizar un vulgar session_start(), porque como comento no puedo destruir la sesión al menos en el mismo método. y mantener sesiones activas es una mala practica.

Comment: de nada! te sirve usar el método propuesto?, si es así marca como resuelta tu pregunta para que quede para las futuras generaciones

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers